# Is running an online business (website, revenue by Google Adsense) a good option to immigrate to Canada as a self-employed person?

Tags: canada, self-employment

Asking for a friend.

He runs an online business and has decent revenue per month for years. Is self-employed project a good choice for him to join Canada?

He develops the code and writes the content for most of the website and hires some outsource editors for routine jobs.

Comment: Under what category does he intend to immigrate?

Comment: authors and writers.